# buidling a form for prayer word on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am stuck on creating a form for prayer requests on WordPress.

We want users to be able to submit a prayer form and choose the praying type, it will then generate a template message inserted with users' inputs (name and the name of the person he is praying for). The form entries will then be sent to a back-end dashboard for the admin's approval before posting it on the prayer wall page.

We have about 4 template messages that we want to put into the form. Anyone can point me to a solution or a plugin that I can use on WordPress?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use gravity + custom post type plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-custom-post-types/